# Sync photos inside the Pictures folder

Tags: macos, icloud, photos

I am new to Mac, so this might be a silly question.

On my Mac Air, I have the iCloud Photo sync turned on. I can see the photos coming from my iPhone.

However, each time I place a picture inside the "Pictures" folder under the user home, it is not syncing. Am I placing it in the wrong place? How to ensure that the pictures I have on my Mac gets synced to iCloud photos?

In Windows, with OneDrive, I can just place the pictures inside the Pictures folder and I am all set.

Here is the location where I try to save my pictures:

[image: Is this the correct place to save my pictures for syncing?]

Comment: As well as the answer below, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303846/macos-does-activating-icloud-preserve-pictures-folder-structure?rq=1 Similar question. Same misunderstanding. It really is very tricky for those new to Macs. Not a silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting photos into the Photos app is not done by copying the file.

You need to do this from inside the Photos app.

Choose File->Import from the menu and then select your files to be imported.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. So, if I want to ensure that the pictures inside the "Pictures" folder are synced, I have to import them to the Photo app?

Comment: Yes that is correct. That is also needed to make them visible in the Photos app on the Mac

Comment: Thanks again. Is there any way to make this process automated? I was thinking to copy all my OneDrive photos inside my "Pictures" folder and have iCloud sync them for me automatically

Comment: Where do your new photos originate.

Comment: Well, I have OneDrive setup also on my Mac. So the pictures are there. I thought about moving them to the "Pictures" folder of the mac for easier faster sync with iCloud

Comment: In that case just import the lot

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and time :)